# Filter with search conditional failing for larger dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm attempting to determine patient compliance for a specific medical treatment, but the function I have written (using apply) only works for data frames with less than ~100 rows.

I have two relevant data frames, which I have slimmed down here to protect patient data: 
'Advice' which contains treatment advisory entries indexed by a unique patient identification number (UID)

```
> head(Advice)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   UID [3]
       UID eyepartid Proctype     entereddatetime    
     <dbl> <chr>     <chr>        <dttm>             
1 11556127 1         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 12:54:18
2 11556127 2         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 12:54:18
3  2680380 2         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 10:40:22
4  2680380 1         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 10:40:22
5 11275381 2         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 13:01:04
6 11275381 1         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 13:01:04
```

and 'Treatments' containing entries recording when patients actually came in for their advised medical treatment and are also indexed by UID.

```
>head(Treatment)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
       UID eyepartid lasertype               entereddatetime    
     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>                   <dttm>             
1 11333944         1 Retina Laser Laser Type 2017-04-21 12:42:49
2 12022346         1 Yellow                  2017-11-01 09:18:42
3 12123496         2 Green                   2017-11-20 16:11:43
4 12291214         1 Yellow                  2017-12-23 10:21:45
5 11005906         2 Yellow                  2017-12-23 13:13:48
6 12341193         2 Green                   2018-01-19 09:12:26
```

As a very rough estimate, the first analysis I wanted to do was to see how many times patients were coming in within 30 days of their doctor's advice for a treatment (since most advice entails 3 treatments).

To accomplish this I was using this simple, and likely inefficient algorithm to append a new column to the advice data frame:

```
Advice$treatments <- apply(Advice, 1, 
function(x) {

  # get date of the advice entry
  AdvisedDay <- x["entereddatetime"]

  # take the subset of Treatment that has the correct UID and is within 30 days 
  ## of the advice entry
  TreatSubset <- filter(UID_Treatment, UID == x["UID"], 
  (difftime(Treatment$entereddatetime, AdvisedDay, units = "days") <= 30)) 

  #return the number of rows in TreatSubset
  nrow(TreatSubset)
})
```

What I am struggling with is that this algorithm works perfectly when I call it on `head(Advice)`
or any slice of the Advice data frame < 100 rows, but returns zero for every row when I call it on the entire Advice data frame.

For instance:

```
adviceToy <- Advice[1:10, ]
```

*Run above function on adviceToy*

```
>adviceToy
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   UID [7]
        UID eyepartid Proctype     entereddatetime     treatments
      <dbl> <chr>     <chr>        <dttm>                   <int>
 1 11556127 1         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 12:54:18          3
 2 11556127 2         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 12:54:18          3
 3  2680380 2         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 10:40:22          0
 4  2680380 1         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 10:40:22          0
 5 11275381 2         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 13:01:04          1
 6 11275381 1         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 13:01:04          1
 7 11557272 3         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 14:22:53          2
 8 11492720 2         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 13:04:41          2
 9 11030362 3         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 15:27:36          2
10 11244084 3         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 17:06:16          0
```

Which is the expected output. But...

*now run function on full advice data frame*
*no warning messages*

```
>Advice
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   UID [3]
       UID eyepartid Proctype     entereddatetime     treatments
     <dbl> <chr>     <chr>        <dttm>                   <int>
1 11556127 1         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 12:54:18          0
2 11556127 2         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 12:54:18          0
3  2680380 2         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 10:40:22          0
4  2680380 1         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 10:40:22          0
5 11275381 2         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 13:01:04          0
6 11275381 1         Retina Laser 2017-06-14 13:01:04          0
```

The same function now returns all zeros for treatments.

Any thoughts on what could be the root of this problem?

Note: I have already cleaned the data of any NA or NULL values

Edit: Added some sample code. Additionally, I have noticed that my Advised data frame has some attributes attached
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some sample data ?

Comment: I would guess that somewhere `AdvisedDay` is being assigned as `NA`.  Without a reproducible example, it's hard to narrow it down with any confidence.

Comment: Just added some sample code @Joyvalley Would calling a stop() if (is.na(AdvisedDay) catch this possibility?

Comment: to my dear ophthalmologist colleague. We all love Stackoverflow and doing this in our free time - meaning please reduce your problem to the minimum. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve